# jquery copy submit value to text input

Tags: jquery

On my site, I have one input text field where a user can enter keyword, and next to it, a submit button to submit the entered keyword.

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
<input type="submit" id="analyse" value="Analyse">
```

Below this input, I also give the user a list of 260 keyword suggestions, which they can choose from incase they don't want to enter any keyword by themselves.
That list is in form of submit buttons.

```
<input type="submit" id="keyword1" value="Example Keyword 1">
<input type="submit" id="keyword2" value="Example Keyword 2">
<input type="submit" id="keyword3" value="Example Keyword 3">
<input type="submit" id="keyword4" value="Example Keyword 4">
[...]
<input type="submit" id="keyword259" value="Example Keyword 259">
<input type="submit" id="keyword260" value="Example Keyword 260">
```

My goal is that if one of the 260 keyword suggestions is clicked, it will copy that value into the top keyword input field, and automatically trigger the main submit button.

I can't think of any efficient solution, because each one has a different ID.
All I can think of, is to create 260 different jquery codes to address each ID.

```
$("#keyword1").val($("#keyword").val());
$("#keyword2").val($("#keyword").val());
$("#keyword3").val($("#keyword").val());
[...]
$("#keyword260").val($("#keyword").val());
```

There has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: Can you give the keyword suggestion input boxes a class? That way you can reference them by class instead of individual ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
          $('.examples input').click(function(e){
            $('#keyword').val($(this).val());
            $('#analyse').click();
          });
        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
      <input type="submit" id="analyse" value="Analyse">

    </form>
    <div class="examples">
      <input type="submit" id="keyword1" value="Example Keyword 1">
      <input type="submit" id="keyword2" value="Example Keyword 2">
      <input type="submit" id="keyword3" value="Example Keyword 3">
      <input type="submit" id="keyword4" value="Example Keyword 4">
      <input type="submit" id="keyword259" value="Example Keyword 259">
      <input type="submit" id="keyword260" value="Example Keyword 260">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

**Description**

```
//On Document.Ready
$(function(){
    //Bind to when in the class examples an input is clicked
    $('.examples input').click(function(e){
        //Set the value of the element with id keyword to the element that was clicked value
        $('#keyword').val($(this).val());
        //Click the element with id analyse
        $('#analyse').click();
    });
});
```

We organized all your examples into a `div` with the class of `examples` this allows us to do the above jQuery selector.

```
<div class="examples">
    <input type="submit" id="keyword1" value="Example Keyword 1">
    <input type="submit" id="keyword2" value="Example Keyword 2">
    <input type="submit" id="keyword3" value="Example Keyword 3">
    <input type="submit" id="keyword4" value="Example Keyword 4">
    <input type="submit" id="keyword259" value="Example Keyword 259">
    <input type="submit" id="keyword260" value="Example Keyword 260">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loop : [Loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

```
for(var i=1; i<=260 ;i++){
    $("#keyword"+i).val($("#keyword").val());
}
```

Comment: why not just select via input type submit?

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
<input type="submit" id="keyword1" value="Example Keyword 1">
```

to

```
    <input type="button" class="keywordSuggestion" value="Example Keyword 1">
    <input type="button" class="keywordSuggestion" value="Example Keyword 2">
    <input type="button" class="keywordSuggestion" value="Example Keyword 3">
....
    <input type="button" class="keywordSuggestion" value="Example Keyword 260">
```

Jquery:

```
$('.keywordSuggestion').click(function(){ $('#keyword').val($(this).val());});
```